Highlight flexible space in a LaTeX pdf?
Is there an easy way to highlight the flexible space that LaTeX inserts when laying out a document? For example, if it adds a little space before or after a paragraph to do widow/orphan protection, then I would like to see that highlighted in some way. Specifically, if there is built in space before a section heading, then I wouldn't want that to be highlighted. I am primarily interested in line-level spacing and not word-level spacing.

I was guessing there might be a way to get latex to highlight the spaces during the compilation process since it knows why it is putting some character at a particular location. I guess one idea could be set the background color to light red and then highlight all of the lines with white. Ideally, the minimal spacing set up by the particular document class would be highlighted so any red that remained would be the "extra space" that wasn't necessary.

Is there a way to migrate this question to tex.stackexchange.com?

Are you looking for something like https://ctan.org/pkg/lua-visual-debug ?

@KJ No idea. I find the question without an example not that clear.
